# FSCalendar's event dot does not appear

Tags: ios, swift, fscalendar

FSCalendar's event dot does not appear. until I swipe to the next or previous month, the event dot doesn't show up. I do use calendar.reloadData() here is my code:

```
 func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, numberOfEventsFor date: Date) -> Int {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "fa_IR")

    for dateStr in dates{
        if(dateFormatter.string(from: date) == dateStr)
        {
            return 1
            self.calendar.reloadData()
        }
    }
    return 0
}
```

I am also using calendar.reloadData() in viewDidLoad():

```
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.calendar.firstWeekday = 7

    self.calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "fa_IR")

    self.calendar.select(Date())
    self.calendar.identifier = NSCalendar.Identifier.persian.rawValue
    self.calendar.reloadData()
```

so what am i doing wrong?
I also tried putting my logic in will displaycell but that didn't work either.
here is the whole view controller:

```
@IBOutlet weak var calendar: FSCalendar!

@IBAction func addEventButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let date = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()

    // initially set the format based on your datepicker date
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

    let myString = formatter.string(from: date)
    // convert your string to date
    let yourDate = formatter.date(from: myString)
    //then again set the date format whhich type of output you need

    formatter.calendar = Calendar (identifier: .persian)
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
    formatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "fa_IR")
    // again convert your date to string
    dateString = formatter.string(from: yourDate!)                

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "addEvent", sender: UIView.self)
}

  @IBOutlet weak var tblCalendar: UITableView!


func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar!, didSelectDate date: Date!) {

    eventIndex.removeAll()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    // initially set the format based on your datepicker date
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

    let myString = formatter.string(from: date)
    // convert your string to date
    let yourDate = formatter.date(from: myString)
    //then again set the date format whhich type of output you need

    formatter.calendar = Calendar (identifier: .persian)
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
    formatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "fa_IR")
    // again convert your date to string
    let selectedDate = formatter.string(from: yourDate!)

    var index = [Int()]
    if dates.isEmpty == false{
    for i in 0...dates.count - 1 {
        if dates[i] == selectedDate{
            index.append(i)
        }
        }
    }
        index.remove(at: 0)
    if index.isEmpty == false {
        for i in 0...index.count - 1 {
            let isIndexValid = dates.indices.contains(index[i])

            if  isIndexValid == true {
                let isEventValid = event.indices.contains(index[i])
                if isEventValid == true{
            eventIndex.append(event[index[i]])
                }
            }
    }
    }

    tblCalendar.reloadData()       
}

func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, numberOfEventsFor date: Date) -> Int {
           return 0
}

func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, willDisplay cell: FSCalendarCell, for date: Date, at position: FSCalendarMonthPosition){

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "fa_IR")

    for dateStr in dates{
        if(dateFormatter.string(from: date) == dateStr)
        {
            cell.eventIndicator.numberOfEvents = 1
            cell.eventIndicator.isHidden = false
            cell.eventIndicator.color = UIColor.blue
        }
    }             
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return eventIndex.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    if eventIndex.indices.contains(indexPath.row) == true {
    cell.textLabel?.text = eventIndex [indexPath.row]
    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if eventIndex.indices.contains(indexPath.row) == true {
        let text = eventIndex[indexPath.row]
        if let indexOfCellString = event.index(of: text) {
            tableViewCellNumber = indexOfCellString
        }
    }
    tblCalendar.reloadData()
           self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "infoView", sender: self)
}    

func showArabicSubTitle(date: Date!) -> String!
{
    let dateFormater = DateFormatter()
    dateFormater.dateFormat = "dd"
    dateFormater.locale = Locale(identifier: "fa_IR")

    var calendarDate = dateFormater.string(from: date as Date)        
    let characters = Array(calendarDate.characters)
    let substituteArabic = ["0":"٠", "1":"١", "2":"٢", "3":"٣", "4":"٤", "5":"٥", "6":"٦", "7":"٧", "8":"٨", "9":"٩"]
    var arabicDate =  ""

    for i in characters {
        if let subs = substituteArabic[String(i)] {
            arabicDate += subs
        } else {
            arabicDate += String(i)
        }
    }
    return arabicDate
}

//MARK: - FSCalendarDelegate
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, titleFor date: Date) -> String? {
    L102Language.setAppleLAnguageTo(lang: "fa")

    return self.showArabicSubTitle(date: date)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {

    if firstIndexRemover == true {
        eventIndex.removeAll()
        firstIndexRemover = false
    }                              
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.calendar.firstWeekday = 7
    self.calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "fa_IR")
    self.calendar.select(Date())
    self.calendar.identifier = NSCalendar.Identifier.persian.rawValue

    tblCalendar.delegate = self
    tblCalendar.dataSource = self
    userData = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "userData")
    if userData == true {
        event = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "theEvent") as! [String]
    }else{
        event.append("رخدادی موجود نیست")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(event, forKey: "theEvent")
        if event[0] == "رخدادی موجود نیست"{
            event.remove(at:0)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(event, forKey: "theEvent")                
        }
    }        
    tblCalendar.reloadData()
    tblCalendar.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
     let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete{
        eventIndex.remove (at:indexPath.row)
        for i in 0...event.count - 1{
            let isIndexValid = event.indices.contains(i)
            if isIndexValid == true {
            if event[i] == cell.textLabel?.text{
                event.remove(at: i)
            }

        }
        }
                   UserDefaults.standard.set (event, forKey:"theEvent")
    }
    tblCalendar.reloadData()

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> String?{
    return "حذف"
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool){
    tblCalendar.reloadData()        
}
```

Comment: add a this line`debugPrint("there is an event")` above `return 1` and remove `self.calendar.reloadData()` from `numberOfEventsFor` method, and let me know what prints

Comment: it prints there is an event 31 times 
but i dont get the event dot till i swipe to the next month and then swipe back to current month

Comment: can you post your viewController full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try returning 0 in your `numberOfEvents` method and add your logic at `willDisplayCell`

The following should execute within your condition for number of events in `willDisplayCell`

```
cell.eventIndicator.numberOfEvents = 1
cell.eventIndicator.isHidden = false
cell.eventIndicator.color = UIColor.green
```

This method and `numberOfEventsForDate` is costly. To be efficient, you can limit the number of code executions by sorting your date datasource in ascending order and only execute the above code when you are inside the minimum and maximum date range. You can achieve the same using `numberOfEventsForDate` method, but here you can directly handle the cell's properties.

**EDIT:**

It seems in your updated code, you haven't reloaded your `self.calendar` in `viewDidLoad`. You have only reloaded your `self.tblCalendar`.
Add `self.calendar.reloadData()`. It should work. If not, try adding your calendar reload in main thread:

`DispatchQueue.main.async { self.calendar.reloadData() }`

Comment: it is still not working till i swipe to the next month and then swipe back again

Comment: Did you try what I said? Can u share code of what you have done (Using `willDisplayCell`) ?

Comment: Why use a workaround when the FSCalendar library have a datasource method for that?

Comment: `func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, willDisplay cell: FSCalendarCell, for date: Date, at position: FSCalendarMonthPosition){
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "fa_IR")
         for dateStr in dates{
            if(dateFormatter.string(from: date) == dateStr)
            {
                cell.eventIndicator.numberOfEvents = 1
                cell.eventIndicator.isHidden = false
                cell.eventIndicator.color = UIColor.blue
            }
        }
}`

Comment: @ReinierMelianYes that's right. It should work fine with the `numberOfEvents` method. But by shifting logic to `willDisplayCell`, we can directly manipulate cell we want to add event to.

Comment: @Farbod As ReinierMelian said, please edit your question with your full view controller code. Your current code reloads the calendar after the method returns, which will throw a compiler error. Anyways adding full code would help to find issue fast.

Comment: @BadhanGanesh i added the whole view controller code

Comment: @BadhanGanesh did that. still isn't working. i have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: Hmmm weird. If the dots are visible after scrolling then this is definitely issue with reloading calendar. Try reloading you calendar from Main thread. `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.calendar.reloadData() }`

Comment: @BadhanGanesh i have never worked with DIspatchQueue before. i looked some stuff up but i really dont know how to use it.
can u tell me in what part of my code should i add it ?

Comment: Just copy and paste this where you’re reloading your calendar: `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.calendar.reloadData() }`